# gcloud instance disk space

Tags: linux, shell, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to do some computing on cloud. For this I created a computing instance and then I attached an external storage with about 10TB. But it seemed that I did something wrong and I got only 200GB available for my datalab. Any comment will be helpful

To check this I used

```
df -h
```

and

```
sudo lsblk
```

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from lsblk command, you have the right size of your datalab-pd disk.
But you can use only 196 Gb.
I think this may be because the file system does not occupy the entire disk space.
Need to extend the file system.
As an example if you have ext3 fs need to do:

```
- umount /dev/sdb # Unmount your disk
- e2fsck /dev/sdb # Check file system in your disk
- resize2fs /dev/sdb
```

resize2fs command without any parameters will extend filesystem to all free space on disk.

More info: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1196353